# Laravel 8: GET params can't be accessed in Middleware's Request's inputs

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing, laravel-middleware, laravel-request

I have defined this route in the `web.php` route file:

```
Route::get('/middleware_test_user_project_change/{pro_id}/{projet_id}', function ($pro_id, $projet_id) {
    return 'test';
})->middleware('user.project.change');
```

I have defined this `handle` function in my middleware (which I've added into the kernel with the following entry: `'user.project.change' => \App\Http\Middleware\CheckUserProposition::class`):

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\User;

class CheckUserProposition
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        $projet_id = $request->input('projet_id');
        $pro_id = $request->input('pro_id');
        return $next($request);
    }

}
```

However, both `$projet_id` and `$pro_id` return `NULL` when I access the following URL: `https://XYZ/middleware_test_user_project_change/1/1`

As I've correctly set up the middleware and the routes parameters (which are, finally, GET variables), why can't I use them in my middleware as request inputs?

Comment: try `request('projet_id')` inside middleware

Comment: it works but why? I didn't find any code example containing, without the dollar symbol, `request->` here: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/requests#accessing-the-request + https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/middleware

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-request

Comment: > The request function returns the current request instance or obtains an input field's value from the current request:

So if it's equivalent to `$request->input('foobar');`, why doesn't this latter work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Route parameters are not part of the 'inputs'. They are a separate thing; this is why you don't see them when you get all the inputs with `$request->all()`.

If you want a route parameter you should probably explicitly ask for it:

```
$request->route('projet_id');
$request->route()->parameter('projet_id');
```

Comment: What are inputs? The doc doesn't clearly say it

Comment: the request's payload and the query string are "inputs"